# Find an infinite recognizable not decidable subset of an infinite decidable language

Tags: turing-machines, semi-decidability

If $L$ is an infinite ($|L|=|\mathbb{N}| $) decidable language, prove that it contains:
a) An infinite subset that is not recognizable.
b) An infinite subset that is recognizable and not decidable.

For the (a) I considered all the subsets of $L$, i.e., $\mathbb{P}(L)$.
Since $|\mathbb{P} (L)| = |\mathbb{R}|$, there exists $A \subset L$ that is not recognizable
(for there are not enough Turing machines to recognize them all).
If $A$ were finite, it would be decidable and hence recognizable, which would be a contradiction.
Therefore $A$ is infinite and not recognizable.

For (b) I thought about $B=L\setminus A$.
Then $B$ is recognizable because $A$ is not.
But I'm not really sure.

Comment: If you’re not sure, try proving it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $K$ be the set of indices of Turing machines which halt on the empty input. Consider the following language:

$$X = \{ 0 w : |w| \in K \} \cup \{ 1 w : |w| \notin K \}. $$

You can check that neither $X$ nor its complement are recognizable.

Therefore your proof idea doesn't work. Here is a different idea. Let $w_1,w_2,w_3,\ldots$ be the words in $L$, enumerated according length and then lexicographically (so if $L = \Sigma^*$, the order would be $\epsilon,0,1,00,01,10,11,\ldots$). The language

$$ Y = \{ w_i : i \in K \} $$

is recognizable but not decidable.

Comment: But I don't understand how are you defining Y

Comment: Does it contain all the words whose indices correspond to a Turing machine which halts on the empty input?